# Multiple Comparisons Problem for non-independant subsets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, moving-average, overlapping-data, familywise-error

I'm investigating whether a program was effective or not using BACI analysis and noticed that overall it had no effect (The 2-way ANOVA and non-parametric approach gave a p-value of about 0.5). I want to investigate whether there's any short term effects.

Unfortunately, the data was very noisy and so to smooth things out, I borrowed a technique used in stock market analysis (plotted the daily moving average of the last week) and calculated the p-values for each giving the plot below;

[image: Each point shows the average effect from the week prior to that day. p-values were calculated using a 2-way ANOVA for each subset of data.]

I've heard of the Multiple Comparison Problem and know that I can't just use the same significance level I used for the overall effect (<0.05) but most calculations of Family-Wide Error Rate assume independence of the data.. (adjacent points have days in common to compute the averages).

What significance level should I use to tell whether the peak at day 12 is significant and why?

Comment: Have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem